# Python, replace long dash with short dash?

Tags: python, replace, python-2.x

I want to replace a long dash (`–`) with a short dash (`-`). My code:

```
if " – " in string:
      string = string.replace(" – ", " - ")
```

results in the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./script.py on line 76, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you read PEP 263?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long dash is not an [ASCII character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). Declare encoding of your script, like this *(somewhere on top)*:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

There are also other encodings beside `utf-8` but it is always safe to use `utf-8` if not working with ASCII characters which covers virtually all (unicode) characters.

See [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more info.

Comment: @Wooble: What isn't? `\xe2`? Encoding a long dash to UTF-8 yields a first byte of `\xe2` (then followed by `\x80\x94`).

Comment: Err... Yeah, that'll teach me to copy paste the wrong character. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would like to link another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856932/3751268. However that only worked for Python 2.

Here is a solution for python 3:

```
my_str = '—asasas—'
my_str.replace(b'\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8'), '--')
```

Comment: doesn't work for  ' B—B'