# Dividing a line of text into elements using a common delimiter

Tags: parsing, python-2.7

I have a playlist text file. I'm trying to extract a list of the artists and their songs. There are 39 line items and they appear as:

Rush - Red Sector A
Blues Traveler - Hook

This is a unicode file.

I'm trying to use the '-' as the delimiter and split the lines there:

```
x = open(u'list.txt')

for line in x:

    line = line.strip()

    elements = line.split('-')
    artist = elements[0]
    song = elements[1]
```

I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playlist.py", line 34, in <module>
    song = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It appears the delimiter is not being recognized. If I comment out "song = elements[1]" and print artists, I get the full line of text, delimiter and all.  I've seen similar questions, but I can't get enough insight from their solutions to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right dash? Try to cut and paste the precise symbol from the file you're reading.

Comment: I think the it's not seeing a dash, but some representation of the dash, in unicode: \xe2

Comment: Using your current example it works `"Rush - Red Sector A".split("-")` gives me `['Rush ', ' Red Sector A']` but with the string you had before you edit your question it wasn't working `"Jace Everett – Bad Things Yes – Owner Of A Lonely Heart".split("-")` gives me `['Jace Everett \xe2\x80\x93 Bad Things Yes \xe2\x80\x93 Owner Of A Lonely Heart']`. Follow @jonrsharpe idea of using the symbol from the file directly

Comment: that's what I see too. If I copy and paste the dash for @jonrsharpe i get `File "playlist.py", line 30
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file playlist.py on line 30, but no encoding declared`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the delimiting character '–' you think it's "-" but it's actually a different character that just looks like the hyphen. This character is not in the ASCII table, so we have to tell python we will be using utf-8, which covers almost all characters we might be using.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

x = open(u'songs.txt')
delimiter = '–' 

for line in x:
line = line.strip()
elements = line.split(delimiter)
artist = elements[0]
song = elements[1]
print "{artist} {song}".format(artist=artist,song=song)
```

My previous answers did not address the root of the problem, but this has been a great learning experience for me as well.

Comment: This has also been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149577/python-replace-long-dash-with-short-dash), and is covered in [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Just a note for noobs like me, the encoding notation needs to be all the way at the top of the script. Location, location, location :)