# Remove long dash from string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read the html content from website to Python to analyze the texts there and decide in which category they fall into. I have an issue with long dashes as they go into NoneType when i'm trying to work with them. I have tried several fixes suggested on this site, but none of them have worked.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('website-im-opening')
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
#this does not work
content = content.translate({0x2014: None})
content = re.sub(u'\u2014','',content)
#This is other part of code
htmlcontent = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

for cont in htmlcontent.select('p'):
    if cont.has_attr('class') == False:
        print(cont.strip()) #Returns an error as text contains long dash
```

Any ideas how could I filter out the long dashes from the string in order to work with the other text? I could replace it with short dash or remove completely, they're not important for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should clean the data after the you use bs4 extract it:

1. BS4 will convert some HTML entity, you do not need to do it your self.
2. BS4 will decode the document for your

```

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('website-im-opening')

content = response.read()

htmlcontent = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

for cont in htmlcontent.find_all('p', class_=False):

    print(p.text)
```

```

Comment: Okay, so i'd need to remove the decode('utf-8'), but what do you mean in point 1?

Comment: @Banana check my update, you should do nothing to the HTML code.

Comment: Doing cont.strip() in for loop still gives me NoneType object is not callable error.

Comment: Okay, issue here was that i had BeautifulSoup elements and not strings. Your version works and i'll mark it as an answer. Thanks for the quick replies and your help!

Answer (score 0):

would something like this do the job for you?

```
# will only work if dashes are at either end
>>> a = '—asasas—'
>>> a.strip('\xe2\x80\x94')
'asasas'
```

it just removes the long dashes
could instead use:

```
# can replace '[long-dash]' with '' to remove instead
>>> a = '—asasas—'
>>> a.replace('\xe2\x80\x94', '[long-dash]')
'[long-dash]asasas[long-dash]'
```

or something to that effect if you wanted to know where they were?

Comment: I tried the replace with method you mentioned, returned an error as well.