# How to replace em dash in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the 'em dash' from a pandas DataFrame.
I have tried a bunch of different suggestions. But none of them are working.

This is what I have got

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my_str = 'word—word'
# my_str.replace(b'\xe2\x80\x94'.decode('utf-8'), '--')
my_str.replace('—'.decode('utf8'), 'xx')
#my_str.replace('\u2014', 'x')

print(my_str)
```

I am trying to simply replace the em dash '—' with something else.

I am always getting an error.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

am stuck on this.  any help appreciated. thanks

Links I have used:

[link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149577/python-replace-long-dash-with-short-dash)

[link two](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2014)

===========

Solution thanks to @Corralien. I am adding a few more points to solve this problem, since it was driving me bonkers.

First check the unicode character you are dealing with using

```
print(ord(u'—'))
```

then look it up here

[unicode lookup](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)

find the python source code for it. in my case it was returned as 8212 which is in python

```
u"\u2014"
```

in python2.7 you need to start the string with 'u' since only from version 3 onwards python interprets every string as unicode by default. so for python 3 use

```
"\u2014"
```

fyi lastly the utf-8 hex representation works as well

```
.str.replace('\xe2\x80\x94', '+')
```

which corresponds to the utf-8 hex representation

```
0xE2 0x80 0x94
```

i hope this helps future visitors, at least i will be able to look this up next time before wasting hours debugging.

PS. in order for str.replace to work you need to use it on a single column only.  str.replace doesnt work for multicolumn dataframes.
so i used it as such:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(u'\u2014', '+')
```

replacing the column in question with a column where the emdash is replaced with a +.

Comment: WHERE are you getting that error?  Is it on the `print` statement?  If so, then you're probably on Windows, and your substitution is working just fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts i am on a ubuntu/linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the unicode representation of ['Em dash'](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2014)

```
>>> my_str.replace('\u2014', '*')
'word*word'
```

From a dataframe:

```
>>> df['col'].str.replace('\u2014', '*')
0    word*word
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: i am baffled. i created a dataframe in a test file and doing this replace df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].str.replace('\xe2\x80\x94', '+')  works there, but not in my original dataframa. it has the same type. could there be a format problem? how do i find out if the format of a string in a dataframe is 'ascii' or 'utf-8'? i am using Python2.7 btw.

Comment: Is your file is a csv? Do you use `encoding` argument with `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: I am fetching it from SQL (VARCHAR200) and it looks like an emdash. Is it maybe not an emdash but an endash? where can i lookup the character encoding? somewhere i can copy and paste the character and get the 'u' code?

Comment: [En Dash](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013): \u2013

Comment: Try: `[hex(ord(c)) for c in my_str]`